# Java relative path not finding file in Program files but finds it on desktop

Tags: java, windows, file

I'm getting an IOException when trying to open a file using relative path. I've compiled the project into a jar and the files I want to load are in a 'images' directory which is in the root directory of the project.

I do not get an exception and I'm able to see the file when I put my project folder on my desktop. However If I put the folder and try to run the application in C:\Program files(x86)\MyApplication then I get the exception. Is this a firewall/permissions issue? I don't see why it works on the desktop but not in program files?

Directory structure of my project:

- MyApplication.jar
- images

This is causing the exception:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new file("images/myimage.jpg"));
```

(I've tried both back & forward slashes)

Comment: Relative paths are resolved relative to the current working directory (which is not necessarily the location of the jar file). How exactly do you run the application?

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: i remember running into a similar issue when i compiled my code into a jar. it couldn't find any of the images even thought they were packed together with the code into the jar. it had something to do with the manifest file in the jar. hopefully that at least points you in the right direction

Comment: I'm not packing the images in the jar though. The images directory is outside of the jar. Even so, it wouldn't explain why it works on the desktop and not in folders like 'Program files'.